# Information about user how liked my page/group

Tags: facebook

After a user clicked on a "like" button of a facebook group or facebook page is it possible to get any addional information about the user beside name and uid?

I know with an app I can request access to a lot of data but I don't want to do that. I also know about facebook statistics.

The question targets more at the point if I publish any information about me if I like something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user ID isn't included in the callback on the edge.create event when a user clicks like, so the page doesn't get it then.

If you get a user ID via the user authorising your app you can access their public information at https://graph.facebook.com/ but you'll need them to allow additional permissions to see anything which wouldn't be accessible to a logged-out user.

Comment: The public informations of course. Thanks.The user_id is also in the [signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) that is send to you app.

Comment: Not unless the user already authorised the app some other way. A regular page impression for a user who hasn't authorised the app won't give you the user id of that user (unless i'm very much mistaken?)

Comment: You are right. I just checked it. You only get the country, the language and an aproximated age. For apps in a tab signed request also includes if you like the page, the page id and if you are admin.

So you get no user id and not even public informations about the user without auth request.